# Probability generating function for $\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{\infty\right\}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, generating-functions, distribution-theory

Assume we have a random variable $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow (\mathbb{N}_\infty, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}_\infty))$ with $\mathbb{N}_\infty=\mathbb{N}\cup(\left\{\infty\right\})$ with distribution $\mathbb{P}_X$ for a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $\mathcal{F}$. Usually we define for a discrete r.v. the probability generating function $\pi$ as:

$\pi(z)=\mathbb{E}[z^X]= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}z^k\cdot \mathbb{P}_X(k)$ for $z\in [0,1]$.

How can we extend this notion to cases where we expect even infinite values of $X$ with positive probability?

For example if we set $X=\infty$, then we would expect that $\pi(z)=0 \quad \forall z\in [0,1)$ and $\pi(1)=1$, because $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}z^x=0$ for $z\in [0,1)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}1^x=1$ with the above notion. So if we want to extend somehow the notion above, we have to add to the series something like $\mathbb{P}_X\left\{\infty \right\}$.

Is there already a common used extension for the case above?

Comment: Why doesn't $\pi(z) = E(z^X) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \infty}z^k P(Z = k)$ work? With $z^{\infty} := \lim_{s \to \infty}z^s$ it becomes what you said.

Comment: I'm concerned about some nice properties of the prob. generating function like if for two r.v. $X,Y$ with $\pi_X=\pi_Y$ then we have $\mathbb{P}_X=\mathbb{P}_Y$. Which maybe doesn't work if for example $X$ takes $\infty$ with positive probability and $Y$ not.

Comment: Okay, I think my concerns are dispensable, because if $\pi_X(z)=\pi_Y(z)$ for two r.v. $X,Y$ then $\mathbb{P}_Y(\infty)=1-\pi_Y(1)=1-\pi_X(1)=\mathbb{P}_X(\infty)$